# How to use NSIS to generate the installer using the files that were generated using visual studio

Tags: nsis

I have generated different dlls and .exes from my C++ and C# projects using visual studio 2017.

Now i need to use these files (dlls, .exes, etc) to generate the Installer using NSIS (Nullsoft).

I wanted to know how to start this (Best way to start)?

Can i start creating NSI script and also here can i add the script for the files those were generated?

I opened existing NSI script and wanted to know which kind of script it is?

Please help me as I am new to NSIS (Nullsoft).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSIS .NSI script files are just text files and they are parsed by the MakeNSIS compiler. NSIS is not related to Visual Studio in any way but there is a 3rd-party commercial NSIS extension for Visual Studio available.

The most basic installer looks like this:

```
Name "My App"
OutFile "mysetup.exe"
InstallDir "$ProgramFiles\My App"

Page Directory
Page InstFiles

Section
SetOutPath $InstDir
File c:\mysourcefiles\MyApp.exe
File ..\dlls\myapp.dll
SectionEnd
```

For a slightly more advanced installer that also has a uninstaller, take a look at [Example2.nsi](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Examples/example2.nsi).

Comment: Hi Anders,   Thank you for the detailed information and please help me how to use one .NSI file into another. I want to create registry entries in one .NSI file and use it into our MY APP.NSI file.

Comment: You can use `!include` to include the contents of one file into another.